# Dynamic Grafana thresholds, Thresholds using Variables or Thresholds on String value

Tags: sql-server, grafana, grafana-variable

I am using `Grafana` to create a dashboard where my data source is `SQL Server` and the threshold I would like is either:

1. A Dashboard variable.
2. String value from a column

I have created a variable that queries the DB and updates the variable: `$UpperLimit`. And is it possible to use that variable as threshold values for coloring purpose?

Or is it possible to use `Strings` (`Regexs`) for Thresholds? 
`[low, medium, high]` which would then color the cell `[green, orange, red]`

Comment: Not an option yet https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/922

Comment: @jbuddy sorry for so sudden, just a wonder, how about using string value for threshold? I didnt found any related tutorial for that.